# check for extended permissions with new facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook

is there a way to check in my application (canvas) if the user has extended permission (for example "stream.publish")?

i only can find a solution for the old sdk.

thanks!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Update at the end of 2011:

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
    console.log(response);
} );
```

console output:

```
{
    data: [
        {
            create_note: 1,
            installed: 1,
            photo_upload: 1,
            publish_stream: 1,
            share_item: 1,
            status_update: 1,
            video_upload: 1,
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is a much better solution since it uses the modern Graph API, thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am using the basic example which comes with the Facebook php sdk, so how to use this code since it gives me an error?

Comment: @pal4life we're discussing the **javascript** sdk here :)

Comment: It works, thanks, but leads to a subtle problem. The request is asynchronous. Imagine that your user clicks on a button, you call this `FB.api`, get a response that the app hasn't the required permission, and then you're trying to ask for that permission, calling `FB.login`. The popup will be blocked by browser, because you have lost your trusted context in the async callback.

Answer (score 16):

### this solution is deprecated at the end of 2011, please use the answer that is marked as accepted above

found a solution myself

```
function check_ext_perm(session,callback) {
    var query = FB.Data.query('select publish_stream,read_stream from permissions where uid={0}', session["uid"]);
    query.wait(function(rows) {
        if(rows[0].publish_stream == 1 && rows[0].read_stream == 1) {
            callback(true);
        } else {
            callback(false);
        }
    });
};
```

this will check for `publish_stream`and `read_stream`

example use:

```
check_ext_perm(response.session, function(isworking) {
   if(isworking) {
      // post something to wall
   } else {
      // ask for login
   }
});
```

Comment: I believe now this should use `response.authResponse` instead of `session` and `response.authResponse.userID`` instead of  `session["uid"]`

Answer (score 1):

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'permissions.request',
    perms: 'user_website',
    display: 'popup'
    },function(response) {
        alert(response.toSource());
        if (response && response.perms) {
            alert('Permissions granted: '+response.perms);
        } else if (!response.perms){
            alert('User did not authorize permission(s).');
        }
});
```

Comment: I believe this ASKS for a permission, not checking

Comment: No it hasnt it works for me still.... but if you want to use the other solution down below your free my friend

Comment: One note on this...the popup will be blocked by most browsers if the check isn't initialized from a user click, so if you want to do this as page loads, better to use FQL or FB.Data.query

Answer (score 1):

Generalized choise's function,

```
function check_permissions (permissions, uid, cb) {
  FB.Data
    .query('select {0} from permissions where uid={1}', permissions, uid)
    .wait(function (res) {
      if (!res || res.length < 1) return cb(false);
      var row = res[0];
      var aperm = permissions.split(',');
      for (var i = 0; i < aperm.length; i++) {
        if (row[aperm[i]] != 1) return cb(false);
      }
      return cb(true);
  });
}
```

Calls the callback with true if the user has all of the permissions, otherwise calls the callback with false.

Answer (score 1):

The responses here that use `FB.Data.query` are to be avoided as this point, as Facebook has deprecated `FB.Data.query` entirely.  The `FB.api`(/me/permissions  ...) solution seems best.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get permissions back from FB.login:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  // handle the response
}, {
  scope: 'publish_actions', 
  return_scopes: true
});
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.1#options