# return message for facebook connect to tell when user clicks skip rather than allow

Tags: php, facebook

I'm putting facebook login on my site. Everything works fine when a user clicks "allow" when asked "My Website would also like permission to". But when user clicks "skip", I need to know this and log them onto my site but not post to their wall. How can i find this out through the facebook api?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check if a user has granted a certain set of permissions to my PHP app?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8478246/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-granted-a-certain-set-of-permissions-to-my-php-app)

Comment: yep, that answers my question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the user/permissions-connection, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fpermissions

See also: [check for extended permissions with new facebook javascript sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388367/check-for-extended-permissions-with-new-facebook-javascript-sdk)