# Facebook All.Js new error

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a website using the Facebook JS SDK and it's working perfectly since over  2 years

Today the Facebook part (i use the SDK to display the user time line in a tab in the main page) stopped working and when the page loads it gives me this JavaScript error

Any help will be appreciated

Error: Error: Expression is of type string, not object
Source File: http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
Line: 37

Answer (score 5):

It isn't as simple as just replacing `FB.Data.waitOn` and `FB.Data.query`.

I was currently using the `FB.Data.query` function call to make `FQL` calls to elegantly test whether or not a user has accepted the `publish_stream` permission of my application(s). 
Like this:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    var user_id = response.id;
    var query = FB.Data.query('select publish_stream from permissions where uid={0}', user_id);
    query.wait(function(rows) {
        if (rows[0].publish_stream == 1) {
            //user has accepted our publish_stream permissions
        } else {
            //user has not accepted our publish_stream permissions
        }
    });
});
```

After googling and searching that awful facebook developers forum; I wasn't able to find what I was looking for until I came across another post here [check for extended permissions with new facebook javascript sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388367/check-for-extended-permissions-with-new-facebook-javascript-sdk)

I was then able come up with my solution:

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response) {
    if (response && response.data) {
        var permissions = response.data.shift();
        //console.log(permissions);
        if (!permissions || (!permissions.publish_stream) || (permissions.publish_stream == 0)) {
            //user has not accepted our publish_stream permissions
        } else {
            //user has accepted our publish_stream permissions
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: same here. Turns out FB.Data.query doesn't work anymore. Just replace it by a FB.api call. it worked for me !

Comment: It should be deprecated on 1st of January, 2012, but it was only today.

Have a look at: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/561/

Comment: I added extra checks to avoid "undefined" problems in case of unexpected server behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply , I suddenly now works without any edit ,Any way if FB.Data.query will be deprecated , we must then use the new method, Thanks again