# Facebook graph API log people out?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cookies, facebook-javascript-sdk, session-cookies

So I made some changes to permissions in our website that uses the facebook graph. (It now allows users to have it automatically post to their activity [video.watches]).

However, it seems that users have to logout of facebook on our site and then re log in to have this activated. How can I make it so users do this? Not sure if it's normal, so any help would be great! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem. You dont need to logout users :)

I did this:

1. Let the user come your website.
2. Check if the user is loggedin or not.
3. If he is, then fetch his extended permissions.
4. Check the extended permission, it will be either true or false.
5. If he has accepted the permission, continue normally
6. If no, present the user with login box (with new scope permissions)

For fetching extended permissions check this: [check for extended permissions with new facebook javascript sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388367/check-for-extended-permissions-with-new-facebook-javascript-sdk)

It is for JS, but can be implemented in other languages as well.